# proving convergence of a power series with the use of another power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

Let <$a_n$> be a sequence of nonnegative numbers such that $\sum_{n\ge1} a_{{_2}{^n}} $ converges.Prove that $\sum_{n\ge1} a_n $ converges.

I tried but couldn't find a way to prove this.Any help to do this please

Comment: Well, since you're missing an essential condition, it's no wonder that you couldn't prove it. Consider $a_n = \frac1n$ for a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

As written, this result is false:

Consider $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=1,
$$
whereas
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}
$$
is known to diverge.

So, you are missing some conditions here.  It is not enough just to add that $a_n$ is non-increasing; I believe you also need to change your assumption to
 convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^na_{2^n}.
$$
With these added assumptions, this is a classical result known as [Cauchy Condensation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.This problem was in one of my notes.